# How to create a unique key for a column in a Cosmos DB collection?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, unique-key

I read this article but here it only writes about Unique key per partition: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/unique-keys.

It is given in the above link that, unique keys cannot be created for existing collections in a container.

Can someone please suggest solutions to a create unique index for existing collections in a container?

Answer (score 0):

A unique key is something which logically partition the values in the container. In the shared document it has already been mentioned that unique key can only be created when creating the Azure Cosmos container, because unique key policy defines the structure (you can say Schema) of the container which prevent any duplicate entries afterwards.

Now, suppose if anybody wants to create new unique key within the container, it might conflict the existing unique key and therefore the complete structure will need to be redesigned. That's the reason, changing and adding new unique key in existing container isn't supported.

The possible workaround to achieve the requirement is:

> To set a unique key for an existing container, create a new container
> with the unique key constraint. Use the appropriate data migration
> tool to move the data from the existing container to the new
> container. For SQL containers, use the Data Migration tool to move
> data. For MongoDB containers, use mongoimport.exe or mongorestore.exe
> to move data.

Other possible way is to implement a logic programmatically to check the uniqueness of the elements for any column before inserting the values into the Cosmos DB. You can try [pre-triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/how-to-write-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs?tabs=javascript#pre-triggers) to implement the checks.